# LINQ To Entities running queries multiple times and Timeout Expiration 

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a site using LINQ To Entites to work against the db.

I often encounter an exception:

> Expiration time out exception

I checked SQL Profiler and I see that certain queries seem to execute often (instead of once as expected). These queries take a long time.

When I run the query against the database directly, it executes quickly.

[Screenshot of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkU65.png)

What is the cause of this, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Did you try increasing the command timeout property something like  myObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 10;

Comment: hi habib, thank you for your answer but this is not the problem because the query shouldn't take more than 2 seconds to complete and the time out is default 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For the selected query in the profiler the duration is 30176 milliseconds which is more than 30 seconds. Here is your timeout. You need to look at the database and figure out why the query that is supposed to take 2 seconds (which still seems a lot) takes 30 seconds.

Comment: the query takes a long time through linq, but when I run the query directly through sql then it is very fast. You can assume the problem is in the linq code, but the problem it is inconsistent, where is the same query which usually get stuck can sometimes run smoothly. plus the problem persist more often in production and hardly in developement.  could it be that my connections don't get disposed for some reason and causing that issue?

Comment: There are known cases where EF can spend significant amount of time preparing queries. This is related to more advanced mapping scenarios like TPT. In that case however you would probably see the problem consistently in both environments. What I was trying to say that the screenshot you had sent clearly showed that it took the database more than 30 secs to execute this query. I think the way to go here is to figure out whether this is the EF or Database problem first. If this is EF then you this may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

Comment: You can see some delays if you are leaking (i.e. not closing)connections indeed. Under a heavier load you would probably see an exception saying: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool." If the load is not heavy garbage collector may be able to dispose the connection object after you invoked connection.Open but before the timeout expires. In your case it is hard to tell what timeout you see as the exception message is pretty generic - it can be a timeout getting a connection from the pool, connecting to db or executing the query.

Comment: what do you mean by "Under a heavier load". How would you measure that approximately?   because it happened to me when I called the query a few hundreds times (and I am the only user). Is that reasonable?

Comment: If there is 10 people trying to connect and there is 20 connections in pool everyone gets a connection but if there is 100 poeple only the first 10 will get the connection. If they won't close/dispose their connections the 90 people waiting will not get a connection until garbage collection cleans up. You don't know how long it will take - let's say 15 seconds. After 15 seconds another 10 people will get connections. But 80 is still waiting the timeout is 30 seconds. If it takes more than 15 seconds to clean up after the second batch 80 people will get the timeout getting a connection from the

Comment: (Continued) pool. It is a bit simplistic but it is how it more or less works. I think you should be able to use performance monitor and performance counters to see the behavior of the pool. Also, if you don't get an exception saying "The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool" then this is probably a different problem

Comment: the exception I'm getting is when running a process that calls a certain query a few hundreds (up to a few thousands) times, everytime with different parameters (when I run the query directly through sql - no problem). Can this still be connections issue?

Comment: This is definitely a timeout coming from the database. It is not on the app side. You need to figure out what's going on in the database. Check indexes and locking. I am not a DBA so cannot really help here...